# Drill-down application / Core Data+UITable View+Custom Cell

Tags: iphone, ios4

i am currently working on a test project which has a tab bar, a drill down table list of  Districts --> Schools --> school details.

Data store is using core data/.mysqlite

**Districts' view is a plain table list which list out districts
***Schools' view is a table view with custom cell which display name,address and picture of schools in the selected district
***Detail view is a sectioned table with more details of the selected school.

I have managed to get the district table view setup and display correctly but I am stuck on pushing the 2nd view which is the School view. How could I pass data to the 2nd view or switch the Fetch Result entity?  I have tried with different method but it is having error, probably it's because I am using the wrong method or missing something at didSelectRow

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'School'

I couldn't find out what the problem is. Would be great if anyone could give me some hints on that.

> > DistrictListTableViewController  -- FRO, MOC fetching "District"
> >     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"District" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
> >      [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

@class District;

@interface DistrictListTableViewController : UITableViewController  {
 @private
 NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

> > SchoolListTableViewController -- FRO, MOC fetching "School"
> >     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"School" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
> >         [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

@class School;

@interface DistrictListTableViewController : UITableViewController  {
 @private
 NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

> > Both DistrictListTableViewController & SchoolListTableViewController  .m files are pretty much the same except School View loads the SchoolTableViewCell file, I don't know if this is the right method.
>
> -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>       SchoolListTableViewController *schoolViewController = [[SchoolListTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
>        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mallViewController animated:YES];
>        [schoolViewController release];
>   }

I am pretty new to this, so please tell me where did I do wrong and what is the right method of passing the entity and data to the 2nd view and how.

Thank you very much.

thanks and this is my fetchedcontroller part

> >
>   - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

```
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"District" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


NSSortDescriptor *locateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"territory" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:locateDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"territory" cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[locateDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

return fetchedResultsController;
```

}

so, in the School controller, i would just switch "District" with "School" and sort description with the name of the school.

Comment: It helps if you format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you are seeing `entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'School'` is telling you that Core Data could not find a definition for the `School` model, so before you do anything else, know that you have to resolve this problem first.

It might help to see your code for `fetchedResultsController` so that we can see how you are instantiating the ivar.

Comment: thanks, please take a look at my fetched controller code above, once again, thanks

Comment: the line: `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"District" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];` references an NSManagedObjectContext.  You need to be sure that this is defined properly.